# why all Future.get() throwing CancelleationException in invokeAll with timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have created one callable which prints couple of lines and sleeps for 2 seconds. I have created a main method which creates 10 instances of this callable and pass to invokeALL method of ExecutorService.

```
 service.invokeAll(callableList, 3, SECONDS);
```

when I am iterating returned List of Future objects. I am getting CancellationException.

I am testing whether all *future.get()* call would cause *CancellationException* or only those tasks which could could not complete and were cancelled.

I am getting either all results or all *CancellationExceptions* irrespective of time setting in *invokeALL*.

I was really expecting that at least some tasks would have complete and returned me results when I call *future.get()*.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer.**

All tasks aren't completing in 3 seconds.

**Long answer.**

The TPE will run all of the tasks and wait for them to complete.  It will execute `get` on each future with the 3 seconds as a wait time for the `get` method.  If all tasks completes in less than 3 seconds the list of Futures will return unaffected.

If it doesn't complete in the expected time then the non-completed futures are cancelled.  So if you have 5 tasks and the first 2 completes but 3rd times out, then 3, 4 and 5 are cancelled.

It is stated slightly in the docs

> Returns:
>       A list of Futures representing the tasks, in the same sequential order as produced by the iterator for the given task list. If the
>   operation did not time out, each task will have completed. If it did
>   time out, some of these tasks will not have completed.

and

> Upon return, tasks that have not completed are cancelled.

Comment: But point is that I am getting all tasks cancelled or completed. Its a all or nothing.

Comment: That probably means the first fails to complete in 3 seconds.  The TPE will run through an `cancel` each Future.  If the Future completed, the cancel is a noop.

Comment: And are you sure **ALL** tasks are canceled?  A CancellationException will be thrown if just one is cancelled (assuming you are iterating over each and `get`ing them)

Comment: yes. I am sure because I am getting cancellation exception for each task or getting results of all tasks. so, it leads me to conclude that its all or nothing. whereas documentation seems to suggest that few tasks would be successful.

Comment: Can you write a small test case which demonstrates the all-or-nothing property you're seeing?  Also can you state the JDK version you're using?